# Open the latest version of a file in a folder respecting a pattern

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder that during the day can be updated with files named according to these patterns ("D0_yyyymmdd.xlsx") and ("D1_yyyymmdd"). So, for example we can find "D0_20200506" and "D1_20200506".

I am writing a program where depending on the user request ("D0" or "D1") I have to get the information of the latest version available in the folder. I already have a code that works for openning the latest file, but the code does not respect the user request "D0" or "D1". Having said that, if the user request is "D0" I have to get information from the latest version of files that follow the "D0_yyyymmdd.xlsx" pattern.

Can someone help me?

```
'Force the explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub OpenLatestFile()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date
    Dim closedBook As Object
    Dim GetBookName As String

    GetBookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'Specify the path to the folder
    MyPath = "\\testingcode\"

    'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

    'Get the first Excel file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)

    'If no files were found, exit the sub
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

        'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

        'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
        'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If

        'Get the next Excel file from the folder
        MyFile = Dir

    Loop

    'Open the latest file
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Workbooks(GetBookName).Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Workbooks(LatestFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: How does the user decide if D0 or D1? Does he pick via Dropdown in a cell or is there an InputBox? According to this decision let's e.g. use the variable `Pattern`, you should instead of `*.xlsx"` check for `Pattern & "*.xlsx"`.

Comment: The idea is to click in a button (D0 or D1)... If he chooses the D0 button we run the code for the latest D0 file.

Answer (score 0):

### Choose Either Using Buttons

For `CommandButton1` and `CommandButton2` change their `Caption` to `D0` and `D1`. Then use the following in the `Sheet Code` e.g. `Sheet1`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    OpenLatestFile Me.CommandButton1.Caption
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    OpenLatestFile Me.CommandButton2.Caption
End Sub
```

Now make the sub 'argumented' in the following way:

```
Sub OpenLatestFile(CmdCaption As String)
```

Change the appropriate line by doing the following:

If the filename starts with `D0` or `D1` use:

```
'Get the first Excel file from the folder
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & CmdCaption & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)
```

If the filename only contains `D0` or `D1` use:

```
'Get the first Excel file from the folder
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*" & CmdCaption & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)
```

The sub should stay in a `standard module` e.g. `Module1`.

Comment: It did not work... How will this solve the variant part of the file name? D0_yyyymmmdd or D1_yyyymmdd.?

Comment: I have been changing my answer quite a lot. Have you seen the last addition I made at the bottom. The program stays the same, only it searches one type of files: either the ones starting or containing `D0` or the ones starting or containing `D1`. I still don't know if they start with D0 or D1 or they just contain it. According to this you have to use one of the two solutions at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! It worked... and always start with D0 or D1